# SMTP MAIL FROM AUTH= format to connect to gmail

Tags: smtp, smtp-auth

I have an older PHP system that uses SMTP commands for mail.  We are switching over to gmail and I need to authenticate.  I can connect to the server.  Unfortunately, I get a 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at" message when I send the MAIL FROM command in my PHP code.

```
if (fputs($this->Socket,  "MAIL FROM: \"admin\" <admin@yourdomain.com>\r\n")<0){
```

I cannot find a clear example of adding authentication. I read at http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2554.html that I must add AUTH= to my MAIL FROM command.  I am having troubles interpretting what to put in the AUTH=

```
Examples:
   C: MAIL FROM:<e=mc2@example.com> AUTH=e+3Dmc2@example.com
   S: 250 OK
```

Do you know the format of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do SMTP authentication, but one of them is to use the SMTP `AUTH LOGIN` command.  The transcript of the session would look like this:

```
host: 220 banner_here
client: EHLO StephaniePC
host: 250-name.of.host hello [clientip], pleased to meet you
host: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
host: 250 OK
client: AUTH LOGIN
host: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
client: am9lc21pdGg=
host: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
client: bGV0bWVpbg0K
host: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
client: MAIL FROM: <sender@senderdomain.tld>
host: 250 2.1.0 Ok
client: RCPT TO: <recipient@recipientdomain.tld>
host: 250 2.1.0 Ok
client: DATA
host: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
....
```

The encoded strings that you see above are base64 encoded.  If you have a mail client that is capable of logging, you can try sending a message through gmail, and the transcript of the session should look like the transcript above.

FYI, instead of writing code yourself to do SMTP authentication, you might want to use `phpmailer`.  `phpmailer` can do SMTP authentication, and it's very lightweight and easy to use.